# Create a Map out of a List of String(s) with streams

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `List` of `String`(s), but I want to convert it into a `Map<String, Boolean>` from the `List<String>`, making all of the `boolean` mappings set to *true*. I have the following code.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("ab");
    list.add("bc");
    list.add("cd");
    Map<String, Boolean> alphaToBoolMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String item: list) {
      alphaToBoolMap.put(item, true);
    }
    //System.out.println(list); [ab, bc, cd]
    //System.out.println(alphaToBoolMap);  {ab=true, bc=true, cd=true}
  }
}
```

Is there a way to reduce this using streams?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. You can also use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) to create your `List`. Then use a `Stream` to [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) this with `Boolean.TRUE` like

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ab", "bc", "cd");
Map<String, Boolean> alphaToBoolMap = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), (a) -> Boolean.TRUE));
System.out.println(alphaToBoolMap);
```

Outputs

```
{cd=true, bc=true, ab=true}
```

For the sake of completeness, we should also consider an example where some values should be `false`. Maybe an empty key like

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ab", "bc", "cd", "");

Map<String, Boolean> alphaToBoolMap = list.stream().collect(Collectors //
        .toMap(Function.identity(), (a) -> {
            return !(a == null || a.isEmpty());
        }));
System.out.println(alphaToBoolMap);
```

Which outputs

```
{=false, cd=true, bc=true, ab=true}
```

Answer (score 8):

The shortest way I can think of is not a one-liner, but it's indeed short:

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(k -> map.put(k, true));
```

This is personal taste, but I only use streams when I need to apply transformations to the source, or filter out some elements, etc.

---

As suggested in the comments by @holi-java, many times, using a `Map` with `Boolean` values is pointless, since there are only two possible values to map keys to. Instead, a `Set` could be used to solve almost all the same problems you'd solve with a `Map<T, Boolean>`.

Comment: up-vote, first. I think you should suggest the OP collect  a `Set` rather than a `Map`. then the problem is very easy, :). `Stream.of(...).collect(toSet())` or `new HashSet(Arrays.asList(...))` since `Boolean` only has 2 values in this case.

Comment: @holi-java Hi! Why a `Set`? OP wants a map with the list as keys and `true` always as the value.

Comment: because the usage of using a `Map` with a `Boolean` value is meaningless. almost all of the operations the `Set<String>` can does. if he only want to print the `foo = true` format, just using a `map(it-> "$it = true")` operation.

Comment: @holi-java You *might* be right. But without knowing OP's problem better, such a suggestion would be a little bit wild.

Comment: :), just a suggestion. it doesn't impact your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to mutate an existing `Map<..., Boolean>`, you can use  [`Collections.newSetFromMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap-java.util.Map-).  It lets you treat such a map as a `Set`:

```
Collections.newSetFromMap(alphaToBoolMap).addAll(list);
```

Comment: *The specified map must be empty at the time this method is invoked, and should not be accessed directly after this method returns.*